# Example of Sets sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Anyone can tell me please an example of a set sequence, i don't Have idea whats meaning that.i know the term of a real sequence elements or functions sequence but of sets sequence no. Cuz im studying measure theory and sigma algebras

Comment: Please provide an example of where you have seen this, it will probably help people to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Are you satisfied with my answer? What kind of example do you need? Help us help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by sequence of sets you mean a collection of sets depending on a certain index $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then for instance, 
$$
\left\{[0,n]\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}
$$
is an example of a sequence of sets. It is the sequence $\{\{0\},[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],\dots\}$.